# Why is cross site scripting in URL dangerious if I don't use cookies?

Tags: web-application, xss, appsec

I currently have an XXS problem in this site.

```
https://bbcpanningen.cupweb6.nl:1311/servlet/OMSALogin?msgStatus="><script>alert("hello")  </script>
```

But I don't understand how an attacker can exploit this.
The sites doesn't use cookies so that might be a problem.
I've read something about it, and they all said the attacker had to send a link with the XSS in it.

Comment: The URL looks like a login page, so I expect that site does use cookies. In general, if an attacker can get the victim to click a link they control, they can steal the cookies. This is an example of Reflective Cross-Site Scripting, and there's more information here: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19373/what-is-the-danger-of-reflected-cross-site-scripting

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of other dangers from XSS, not just stealing cookies. Your page could be defaced, data which is secured (for instance with ip-protection) can be stolen or it even can be used to do some time-based attacks on internal networks the attacked browser may be connected to.

So you definitely should have a look at the [OWASP XSS Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) to protect against things like these.

Comment: Dear gentlemen, if you downvote please give at least a small comment how my answer can be improved.